# Load More Data When Scroll to Bottom ListBox Silverlight NOT WP7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, web-applications, listbox

I would like to have a listBox that I will fill with items. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the `listBox`, the `listBox` should be loaded with more items.

There are tons of tutorials for doing this in WP7, but I haven't found anything solid for doing this in a Silverlight web app.

While trying different things out, I managed to create a method that can display a Message when a user scrolls to the bottom of the ListBox. This is more of a proof of concept than a final implementation:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
var childScrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0);
        if (childScrollViewer is ScrollViewer)
            scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)childScrollViewer;

if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
            MessageBox.Show("You're at the bottom!");
```

I'm currently calling this method from the ListBox's `MouseWheel` event. This approach is not ideal since it doesn't account for users clicking on the scrollbar and dragging it down. This implementation is also poor because the message is displayed when the user scrolls to the top **or** bottom of the listbox.

Here some nice WP7 tutorials I found that I wish could be implemented in a Silverlight web app:

- [Here's a WP7 tutorial I can't use](http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)
- [This one seemed promising but is poorly described and doesn't really work](http://www.manas.com.ar/spalladino/2008/07/02/paging-in-data-bound-listbox-in-silverlight/)
- [Here's another WP7 tutorial I can't use](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/150166/Loading-Data-when-the-User-Scrolls-to-the-End-of-a)

I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Whether it's a tutorial, or a concept I can learn about that might do the trick, or anything else that can help me implement this in a Silverlight web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jlikness/making-the-scrollviewer-talk-in-silverlight-4) tutorial saved my life. Here's what I ended up doing:

My `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstEventHistory"
            Grid.Row="1"
            d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/AssetLifeCycleSampleData.xaml}"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="#FFD4D4D6"
            BorderThickness="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource eventsViewSource}}"
            Loaded="initScrollViewerMonitor"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

This method is called by the `ListBox`'s `Loaded` event and attaches a custom binding to the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListBox`. This binding will check for changes in the `ScrollViwer`'s `VerticalOffset` property:

```
private void initScrollViewerMonitor(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
           //get the ScrollViewer from the ListBox
           scrollViewer = lstEventHistory.GetScrollHost();

            //attach to custom binding to check if ScrollViewer verticalOffset property has changed
            var binding = new Binding("VerticalOffset") { Source = scrollViewer };
            var offsetChangeListener = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ListenerOffset",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(UserControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollChanged));
            scrollViewer.SetBinding(offsetChangeListener, binding);
    }
```

Finally, this method is called whenever there are changes to the `VerticalOffset`

```
public void OnScrollChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //We have to check if the values are 0.0 because they are both set to this when the scrollviewer loads
        if ((scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight <= scrollViewer.VerticalOffset)
            && (scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight != 0.0 && scrollViewer.VerticalOffset != 0.0))
        {
            //The ScrollBar is at the bottom, load more results.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Bruno, Can you please let me know how did you get the method scrollViewer = lstEventHistory.GetScrollHost();

I dont see it exists for me in Silverlight project on the ListBox conrol

Comment: Hi, I guess I should have mentioned it but you have to download the Silverlight Toolkit to get access to that method. Depending on you version of Silverlight you can download it [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528) or [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). I believe you can also get it directly from NuGet.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, this code has helped me, btw just a small question I am trying to use this logic, are there any exceptions to this logic?? I mean any corner cases with which it is not working that you are aware of

Comment: The only thing I can think of is running into issues while using older versions of Silverlight. Having said that, I've only had to implement this once so far. BTW, if you found this question helpful don't forget to upvote it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update Bruno, Yeah this Que/Answer was helpful to me and just upvoted.. Thanks